# Why does wusa fail with "The System cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: windows, update

On Windows 7 or later, attempting to use `wusa.exe` to install a CAB file containing a Windows update returns error 0x80070002 (-2147024894), "The System cannot find the file specified".

I've tried quoting the full path to the file, running the command in session zero, and everything else I could think of.  Why won't the update install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in [Description of the Windows Update Standalone Installer in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307), `wusa.exe` is designed for installing updates in the form of `.msu` files.  It cannot install updates that are in `.cab` files.

To install an update in a CAB file, use `dism.exe` instead, e.g.,:

```
dism /Online /Add-Package:B77A6E83F39EA6B1F3AF261B8B8861B382E37B40.cab
```

DISM is documented in [What Is Deployment Image Servicing and Management?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744566%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)